# Cobbler PXE boot : dhcp issue

Tags: dhcp

## Context

I am currently setting up a little cluster. For now, I only have one node configured and running (CentOS 7) : a management node. All the other nodes (compute nodes) aren't configured yet.

[image]

The compute nodes run on RedHat 6, and I am trying to use Cobbler on my management node to provision them with Centos 7.

I have installed Cobbler and configured it to PXE-boot one of my compute nodes and install Centos 7 on it.

The management node is on subnet 10.10.3.64/26, on VLAN n° 1301. The compute nodes' have to be provisionned with ip adresses in that subnet too.

## Cobbler configuration

I have cobbler configured to manage dns & dhcp. I have created a system object representing the node I want to provision.

**/etc/cobbler/modules.conf**

```
[dhcp]
module = manage_isc
```

*(whole file [here](https://gist.github.com/WinstonSureChill/0cca58ff1126101870ea))*

**/etc/cobbler/settings** (relevant settings / settings I have changed)

```
manage_dhcp: 1
manage_dns: 1
bind_master: 10.10.3.65
manage_forward_zones: ['linuxrt']
manage_reverse_zones: ['10.10.3']
next_server: 10.10.3.65
restart_dns: 1
restart_dhcp: 1
server: 10.10.3.65
```

*(whole file [here](https://gist.github.com/WinstonSureChill/0249e7d578d96acf4d1e))*

(can't post more than 2 links, other configuration files linked in commentary)

## Problem

When I'm booting the compute node on PXE, it starts looking for the DHCP server, and then I get that error :

```
PXE-E51: No DHCP or proxyDHCP offers were received.
```

No dhcp logs are generated in /var/log/messages. I also tried to sniff for incoming packages on the management node with `tcpdump`, but I see nothing coming from the compute-node. It seems like the node's dhcp queries don't reach the management node.

Comment: [**/etc/cobbler/dhcp.template**](https://gist.github.com/WinstonSureChill/c5fc2831b8648ac4a638)

Comment: [**cobbler system**](https://gist.github.com/WinstonSureChill/219be0e37c32d15d658a)

Comment: is the management node in the same VLAN as the clients?

Comment: I haven't touched the client nodes, so they might have an old network configuration. Hence, likely not the same VLAN/subnet as my management node. But the whole point of dhcp is to configure the network interfaces of those client nodes, no?

Comment: The DHCP protocol by default relies on the server and clients being in the same broadcast domain. If they're not, DHCP requests won't reach the server unless you define a DHCP helper address.

Comment: That is probably the root of the problem so Imma dig that! Thanks for the piece of information!

Comment: Let me write an answer for that so we can close this question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the switchports of the DHCP server and the clients are in the same VLAN, or use a DHCP helper.

The DHCP protocol by default relies on the server and clients being in the same broadcast domain. If they're not, DHCP requests won't reach the server unless you define a DHCP helper address.

Comment: It was a VLAN problem indeed. The node to be installed was connected on a switch port where trunking was activated, so it needed to tags its data with the good VLAN number, which it was not doing, so it was unable to reach the dhcp server. Thanks mate.

Comment: I just connected the node to-be-installed on a switch port where there was no trunking, and that solved the issue